# how to play specific url audio from Audio List

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

i am new with using `just_audio` plugin and i have list of url that i set them into Player like following

```
AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
 _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    _audioPlayer
            .setAudioSource(ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
          AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
              "https://archive.org/download/IGM-V7/IGM%20-%20Vol.%207/25%20Diablo%20-%20Tristram%20%28Blizzard%29.mp3")),
          AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
              "https://archive.org/download/igm-v8_202101/IGM%20-%20Vol.%208/15%20Pokemon%20Red%20-%20Cerulean%20City%20%28Game%20Freak%29.mp3")),
          AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
              "https://scummbar.com/mi2/MI1-CD/01%20-%20Opening%20Themes%20-%20Introduction.mp3")),
        ]))
```

Now How can i use `_audioPlayer.play()`with one specific url
in other word i need to tell him `play` the `url` that has `index 3`

how implement this , thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the purpose of `ConcatenatingAudioSource` is to play the children one after the other (or randomly with the shuffle options), as if it was one source. The doc doesn't seem to mention seeking to a specific index. I think you can achieve what you want just by re-setting the audio source every time, no ?

Comment: thanks but no , since i have multi audio url paths from server , and when user press so i need to pass the same path that already setting in my ConcatenatingAudioSource but anyway i find out this is not correct way .. any suggestion how to handle it by index would be grateful

Comment: Just keep the list as a state or provider then ? I don't see why it would be any different

Comment: i have onPressed method in listview.bulder . per index is an audio file from server .. once user press on an audio url so i only need the url which been pressed the one who play . also i have all urls set in my ConcatenatingAudioSource if did not specify the index so when user press on any url then the audio player will run the whole list in loop

Comment: and yes that what i doing now re-setting the audio source every time, but that will take a bit delay comparing if they were setting at once

Comment: And how about creating a dedicated AudioPlayer per source ?

Comment: well , after many tests i noticed the only  reason for delay is to make .set() per url ..